Writing a filesystem on top of block device in Linux
I have a custom file-system driver, which is a glorified tmpfs.  I'd like to modify it to run on a zram block device, such that the underlying data is compressed.  Unfortunately, I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what the proper way to do this would be.   One option is to directly modify the super_block's s_bdev field with a pointer to the zram block_device, but I'm not seeing any examples of other filesystems doing this, nor can I find any documentation on anything like this
The other would be to override the f_ops->read_iter/write_iter to modify the zram block device directly, but then I would have to implement a lot of redundant logic to figure out which pages to read, etc.   Would anyone know if there is a standard way of doing something like this?

I don’t understand why you’re thinking about having the super block point to the device.  The super block would be in the device, wouldn’t it?

I have a limitted understanding of block devices/ file_systems, and thier interactions, so I'm likley making some bad assumptions on how all this works...  My understanding is that the file_system deals with filenames, etc, and underneath the file_system is a super_block (an instance where the fs is mounted), which would have some block device which would handle the actual io operations.    In my case I want to mount a filesystem on top of a particular block device (zram).  Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding something
